# Mercurial in WSL: HGEDITOR $PATH is different from my $PATH

Tags: mercurial, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to configure Mercurial inside of my WSL2 instance on windows.

I am on WSL and chose "Ubuntu" as my distro, which gave me 22.04.3 LTS.

I installed mercurial via snap: `sudo snap install mercurial` which gave me hg --version 6.4.4.

`hg` generally works, but when I try to change my editor to the `code` binary, hg can't find that binary in my path. This is despite the fact that it's available in my interactive bash shell:

```
mason@Ryzen-7:~/Documents/Code/coda$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/mnt/c/Program Files/dotnet/:/mnt/c/Program Files/TortoiseHg/:/mnt/c/Users/mason/.cargo/bin:/mnt/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/snap/bin

mason@Ryzen-7:~/Documents/Code/coda$ which code
/mnt/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code
```

As a little hack to find out what PATH hg can see, I updated my editor = echo $PATH. Then when I try to launch an editor, it just prints the PATH that is using when it tries to spawn an editor, and that PATH is, quite surprisingly, different from mine:

```
mason@Ryzen-7:~/Documents/Code/coda$ hg config -e
/snap/mercurial/12/usr/sbin:/snap/mercurial/12/usr/bin:/snap/mercurial/12/sbin:/snap/mercurial/12/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

hg's $PATH, then, doesn't contain the necessary `/mnt/c/Users/mason/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin`.

Why is hg's PATH different from the parent shell, and how can I modify the path that hg sees?

Edit: I tried one more thing. I opened up an interactive python3 shell and tried os.environ. python3 has correctly inherited its parent's enrivonment including my full $PATH.

Comment: Note: I tried to work around this problem by manually specifying the fully-qualified path to the code-binary in the editor= config, but there were additional errors due to an incorrect $PATH, so I really just need to fix the root cause of hg spawning an editor using a different $PATH than my shell has.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a problem with how snapware sandboxes PATH. I was able to get this working right away in apt-get. But I would like to understand how I could have used snapware (which seems to be the future of Ubuntu and which already has higher version of hg).

Comment: snap run --shell mercurial.   Allows testing under snap env. My guess would be snap package doesn't have access to things need to lunch windows versions of code from wsl.

Comment: The magic for starting (windows) code in wsl seems to be %APPDATA%/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code, as it does different things if it detects WSL. one thing is the path mapping tool, "wslpath" is not visible to the snap.

Comment: basically it seems that when code is run in wsl, the code script try's to find "c:\Users\$USER\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl-0.81.8\scripts\wslCode.sh"   (via calling code --locate-extension ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) - this doesn't appear to work in the snap sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too and it was driving me crazy! It's because mercurial was installed via snap and is running in a sandbox. Mercurial doesn't have permission to launch an arbitrary binary from inside snap - that's why it can never find anything.

I got around this by downloading the mercurial source from https://www.mercurial-scm.org/downloads and running from a local installation (no compilation necessary).

I don't know how to get snap to allow mercurial access to other binaries on the filesystem.